# Get Dynamic Vertical Spacing in View of Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have an application in which their is a screen. Which contains some `UIView` inside `UIView`.

Now the height of `UIView`(Parent) is Dynamic. It is adjusting according to Screen Height.

I have placed my `UIView`(child) inside it.

My `UIView` (parent) without Constraints.

[image]

Now,

I have added Following COnstraints:

Constraint to Parent `View`

> Top , Bottom , Leading , Trailing

Constraint added to `SubViews`

> UIView-1 : leading , trailing , top , height
>
> UIView-2 : leading , trailing , vertical spacing (UIView 1) , height
>
> UIView-3 : leading , trailing , vertical spacing (UIView 2) , height
>
> UIView-4 : leading , trailing , vertical spacing (UIView 3) , height

Now I am getting this Screen:

[image]

When I change `UIView 4` Constraint to :

> UIView-4 : leading , trailing , vertical spacing (UIView 3) , height , Bottom

I am getting this screen:

[image]

My Parent view shrinks from `340` to `217` .

But I want to manage the vertical spacing between the views to increase or decrease. What Constraint I am missing.

**Edit**

I have changed the xib size to 3.5 inch and then to freeform. Now I have this much of space. How can I add spacer views?

[image]

Comment: you should give equal height constraint to all of your subviews! Also if you want to have more control for vertical space use blank views as spacers in between those views! And give equal height constraint to the all spacer views and after that select all white subviews and give equal height constraint!

Comment: Should I remove the Height constraint and apply equal height ? @TejaNandamuri

Comment: yes. PLs check my updated commment! @RahulMishra

Comment: @TejaNandamuri yes Thanks I am trying that...and Please see my updated question

Comment: you should add the spacer view between the two white views/ or wherevr you see pink gap and give the spacer view background color as clear color, to make sure your spacing works give it a different color so that you can differtentiate easily, and later you can change it to clear color@RahulMishra

Comment: @TejaNandamuri When I use equal Height after Removing Height(40) Instead of Spacing my `UIViews` get Increased(Height)

Comment: yes, you can't satisfy all constraints. If you want to have the subviews height to be 40, you should manipoulate the spacer views height accordingly so that your subviews height will be 40. Do the math! :)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I have added spacer views and applied constraint. `vertical spacing` to top and bottom view but nothing is happeing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111646/discussion-between-teja-nandamuri-and-rahulmishra).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) for this type of layout.

Or, if you want to keep compatibility with iOS7&8 you should use spacer views. That means that you have to add some dummy views in the empty space between your views and set equal height constraints between all of them.

Comment: I have to support earlier versions of ios. That's why I can't use it

Answer (score 0):

1. Use free form layout
2. Arrange the views in the format

   [image]
3. once you done arranging the layout
4. select all red views, and give all 4 constraints, and additonally give equal height constraint
5. now select all green spacer views and give all 4 constraints (top,leading,trail,bottom) and additionally give equal height constraint
6. Create a property or outlet for the green spacer view height constraint, and you can change it to increase or decrease the red views height!